# VBS Doesn't stop running

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task that launches a vb script which in turn runs a macro within excel.  Everything runs fine (as in I get the results I want), however, the scheduled task remains 'running' and therefore doesn't start again the next morning.  The VB Script is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyPath\My File.xlsm", 0, True)
xlApp.Run "myMacro"
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

The end of the Macro (all the preceding code work and saves my csv output as required):

```
        Workbooks("My File.xlsm").Activate
        Worksheets("Outputs").Select
        'ActiveWorkbook.Save
        'ActiveWorkbook.Close - this line cause vbs to fail after creating my csv
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End Sub
```

How do I terminate the VB Script to stop the scheduled task from running?

Comment: If the CSV has been saved, can you use `ActiveWorkbook.Close False` to close the workbook without further saving?

Comment: Unfortunately, the script still fails with error 800APC68 Unknown Runtime Error.  If I remove that line, that's when it doesn't error.....but doesn't stop either!!!

Comment: If you have an interactive script that works outside Task Scheduler but not within, check out the following: [http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2015/02/18/help-my-scheduled-task-does-not-run.aspx](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2015/02/18/help-my-scheduled-task-does-not-run.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately as you realized:

```
    Workbooks("My File.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("Outputs").Select
    'ActiveWorkbook.Save
    'ActiveWorkbook.Close - this line cause vbs to fail after creating my csv
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Will give you an error due to the fact that the xlBook object is attempting to close the already closed workbook. I believe that if you update VBScript to:

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyPath\My File.xlsm", 0, True)
xlApp.Run "myMacro"
'xlBook.Close Remove this line
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

and add back the ActiveWorkbook.Save and ActiveWorkbook.Close lines, you VBScript & Excel application should close correctly.