# VBS Script doesn't stop running

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

So I saw [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402313/vbs-doesnt-stop-running) and it was not able to solve my problem. I have a scheduled task that I want to run daily. It opens a excel workbook, runs a macro to update something and then never stops running.

Here is the VBS script.

```
Option Explicit

ExcelMacroRun

Sub ExcelMacroRun()

    Dim xlApp, xlBook

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    'xlApp.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    xlApp.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False


    '~~> Change Path here
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("P:\Fido\Automated\DailyPrices\DailyPrices_new.xlsm", 0)
    xlApp.Run "getPriceData"
    xlBook.Save
    xlBook.Close
    xlApp.Quit

    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub

WScript.Quit
```

Here is the macro:

```
Sub getPriceData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo echk

echk1 = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

'Import new fund data into Imports page
    Worksheets("Import").Activate
    Cells.Delete
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="P:\FIDO\Automated\DailyPrices\prices.csv"
    Windows("prices.csv").Activate
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("DailyPrices_new.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("Import").Activate
    Cells.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll

'Import new annuity data into Annuities page
    Worksheets("AnnuityImport").Activate
    Cells.Delete
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="P:\FIDO\Automated\DailyPrices\AnnuityPRA.csv"
    Windows("AnnuityPRA.csv").Activate
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("DailyPrices_new.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("AnnuityImport").Activate
    Cells.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll
```

There is a code block here where it adds a column to the excel file. Deletes a column if it is to long and runs a calculation. Then it comes to this part of the file (the end):

```
Calculate
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic


Exit Sub
 echk:
     'MsgBox Error
     echk = True
     Resume Next
 End Sub
```

It is set to run regardless if the user is logged in. It stays running even if I self start it. I am lost here. Can anyone see what I am missing to why it will not stop running?

Comment: have you tried using the debugger and stepping through the code to see where it is hanging? (would also remove the on error while debugging)

Comment: My guess is that your macro is getting confused on which `Workbook` is active and exactly what columns or cells are being referenced. Take a look at [these](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/11274/always-define-and-set-references-to-all-workbooks-and-sheets#t=20170510203911048245) very good [references](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate#t=20170510203911048245) and see if you can clean up your code to remove the problem.

Comment: I tried your code, prepared both VBS file and VBA macro with proper paths, the script and the macro work as expected, nothing stays running, Win 7 HB x64, Excel 2010 64-bit.